# How to detect if a window is in front of other windows

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, focus

Is there a way to bring a child window in front when the parent is focused? What I am trying to resolve is this: I have a parent window (root) and a child window (TopLevel) called "menu." The child window is a floating menu with several buttons on it and is titlebar-less.

If I set menu.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1) than the child window called "menu" stays on top all the times, even if I open another app the menu stays above all windows, which is not very practical.

If I reset menu.wm_attributes('-topmost', 0) and that I focus on the parent window, the child window stays behind all other windows, and I cannot see it. This occurs if I am running my app and then have to open another app such as Dbeaver or Firefox. I then bring my app to the front but the child stays behind Dbeaver or Firefox.

What I am trying to do is detect when the main window is focused so that I can then bring the child window in the front so that both the root and the toplevel are in the front.

I did some extensive search on the net. Found a lot about detecting if the window is open or closed but nothing about detecting if the windows is open.

I use python 3.8 and tkinter.

Here is what I have so far in that section of the code. Doesn't work perfectly yet but it is very close:

```
def push_menu_front(event):
    focus = 0
    focus += 1
    if focus != 0:
        print("focus is 1")
        menu.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)


def push_menu_back(event):
    focus = 0
    focus += 1
    if focus != 0:
        print("focus is 0")
        menu.wm_attributes('-topmost', 0)


root.bind("<FocusIn>", bring_menu_front)
root.bind("<FocusOut>", bring_menu_back)
```

Comment: bind window to `<FocusIn>` event e.g. `root.bind('<FocusIn>', lambda e: print(e))`, also you should provide a [mre]

Comment: Thank you Matiiss. I will try this suggestion. It's difficult to provide a minimal reproducible example because I have thousands of lines of code and I am not sure what part would be useful, but I will try anyway.l

Comment: Could you look at the code and see if there is a way to find tune this and make it work 100% of the times.

Comment: Did you try to make the child window a *transient* window of the main window?

Comment: acw1668 < No the child windows is permanent. It opens at the same time as the parent. It's a floating menu. What I was trying to do is be able to move both the parent and the child in the back when opening another app on top, and bring back both the parent and the child in front when the parent is in focus again. The solutions below work.

Comment: `transient` window is a child window which is always on-top (z-order) of its parent window.  You don't need to do the focus in an out stuff as the answer.

Comment: acw1668. I didn't know it existed. However, it does not work on Windows if the child has top.overrideredirect(1). With overrideredirect(1) the child does not come up at all. I use the overrideredirect to remove the borders around the child. I wish I could show you a screenshot of the menu I made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using both Matiiss and acw1668 solutions to make this menu/toolbar compatible with both Microsoft Windows and Linux. In the second version below I added a bit more code to show how the menu/toolbar looks like. Both parent and child move to the back when opening another app on top, and both return to the front when selecting the parent again. acw1668' solution reduced the amount of code.

Simple version:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Toplevel, Button
from sys import platform

def start_side_menu():
    global menu
    menu = Toplevel(root)
    menu.geometry("90x300+620+123")
    menu.title("top")
    menu.resizable(False, False)

    # Remove borders in Windows
    if platform == "win32":
        menu.overrideredirect(1)

    # Remove borders in Linux + keep child with parent
    else:
        menu.wm_attributes('-type', 'splash')
        # acw1998 solution to keep the child with the parent with Linux
        menu.transient(root)

def push_menu_front_win(event=None):
    # Matiiss solution to keep the child with the parent with Windows
    menu.attributes('-topmost', True)
    menu.attributes('-topmost', False)

root = Tk()
root.title('master')
root.geometry("300x300+300+100")

# Microsoft Windows OS call this function ----------

if platform == "win32":
    root.bind("<FocusIn>", push_menu_front_win)

start_side_menu()

root.mainloop()
```

Longer version to show final size and buttons on the floating menu:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Toplevel, Button
from sys import platform

def start_side_menu():
    global menu

    menu = Toplevel(root)
    menu_width = 85
    menu_height = 377
    menu.title("")
    menu.resizable(False, False)

    # Remove borders in Windows
    if platform == "win32":
        r = (mon_width / 1) - (menu_width * 5.55)
        t = (mon_height / 2) - (menu_height / 1.2)
        menu.geometry(f'{menu_width}x{menu_height}+{int(r)}+{int(t)}')
        menu.overrideredirect(1)

    # Remove borders in Linux + keep child with parent
    else:
        r = (mon_width / 1) - (menu_width * 5.75)
        t = (mon_height / 2) - (menu_height / 1.5)
        menu.geometry(f'{menu_width}x{menu_height}+{int(r)}+{int(t)}')
        # acw1998 solution to keep the child with the parent with Linux
        menu.transient(root)
        menu.wm_attributes('-type', 'splash')

    # a couple of button just to show how to toolbar looks like
    search_checklist_btn = Button(menu, text='SEARCH', font=('FreeSans', 11), width=11, height=2, bg="#729FCF")
    search_checklist_btn.place(x=0, y=0, width=85)
    save_checklist_btn = Button(menu, text='NEW', font=('FreeSans', 11), width=11, height=2, bg="#729FCF")
    save_checklist_btn.place(x=0, y=47, width=85)

def push_menu_front_win(event=None):
    # Matiiss solution to keep the child with the parent with Windows
    menu.attributes('-topmost', True)
    menu.attributes('-topmost', False)

root = Tk()
root.title('')
root.geometry("920x980+500+20")
mon_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
mon_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

# For Microsoft Windows OS
if platform == "win32":
    root.bind("<FocusIn>", push_menu_front_win)

# start the menu function
start_side_menu()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

With Matiiss' suggestions, I got the following code to work on Windows, not Linux. So I have combined my version of Linux and his version of Windows to work based on the operating system used. There is also a new version that uses a bit less code as seen in accepted answer.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Toplevel
from sys import platform

def push_menu_front_win(event=None):
    menu.attributes('-topmost', True)
    menu.attributes('-topmost', False)

def push_menu_front(event=None):
    menu.attributes('-topmost', True)

def push_menu_back(event=None):
    menu.attributes('-topmost', False)

root = Tk()
root.title('master')
root.geometry("300x300+300+100")

menu = Toplevel(root)
menu.title('top')
menu.geometry("120x300+610+100")

# --------------- Select the OS used with if statement ----------
# Microsoft Windows OS
if platform == "win32":
    root.bind("<FocusIn>", push_menu_front_win)

# MAC OS
elif platform == "darwin":
    root.bind("<FocusIn>", push_menu_front)
    root.bind("<FocusOut>", push_menu_back)

# Linux OS
elif platform == "linux" or platform == "linux2":
    root.bind("<FocusIn>", push_menu_front)
    root.bind("<FocusOut>", push_menu_back)

root.mainloop()
```

This floating windows without border looks pretty cool. It allows me to use the full parent window to display database information, and place the buttons (functions) on the floating menu.

Comment: Just a mention for others. The above code works on Linux only. Matiiss code above works totally fine on Windows. They both do the same thing but on different platform.

Comment: you probably want to add that information in your answer so that it is more visible, you can [edit] your answer

Comment: Yes, I have modified mine and also show how I included both versions so that they work on either Windows or Linux.

Comment: that's excellent, you might as well mark your own answer as accepted since it is more thorough than mine (it includes both systems and how to automatically differentiate between them)

Comment: Also you can remove the two bindings out of the if statements and you would need to define what `platform` is

Answer (score 1):

So there is this much easier solution, mentioned by @acw1668, that is to use `.transient` (which I found out about today):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Toplevel

root = Tk()
root.title('master')

top = Toplevel(root)
top.title('top')
top.transient(root)

root.mainloop()
```

[`.transient` docs (more of a definiton)](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/tkinter.Toplevel.transient)

Comment: I didn't know it existed. It is much simpler and works fine on linux in my case. However, it does not work on Windows if the child has top.overrideredirect(1). With overrideredirect(1) the chid does not come up at all. I use the overrideredirect to remove the borders around the child. So this would work fine on both Windows and Linux if you do not use top.overrideredirect(1) to remove the border.

Comment: I tried to post a screenshot of the menu/toolbar with all buttons on it but this function doesn't seem to work properly in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

So I came up with a completely different way of doing this (it works on windows at least), this works if the `Toplevel` window has `overrideredirect` flag set to `True`:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Toplevel, Label, Entry


root = Tk()
root.title('master')
root.bind('<FocusIn>', lambda _: top.deiconify())

top = Toplevel(root)
top.title('top')
top.overrideredirect(True)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Very interesting. It works on Windows -- not on Linux. On Linux, the child stays on top all the times. It's amazing that there is such a difference between the two OSes. It's definitely another solution for those who use Microsoft Windows only.